# How to include html5sortable in your project?

Tags: javascript, html5sortable

I'm unsure how to include [html5sortable](https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable) in my project. I've installed it using npm:

`npm install html5sortable --save`

After webpack packaged things up I'm importing it as follows:

`require 'html5sortable'`

But when I invoke ([as the docs say](https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable)):

`sortable('.sortable');`

I get:

`sortable is not a function` or `sortable is not defined`

I've also tried the following variations (Livescript):

```
html5sortable = require 'html5sortable'
sortable = require 'html5sortable'
{sortable} = require 'html5sortable'
```

As the documentation says, "*load file you need from the dist/ directory, e.g. dist/html.sortable.min.js*". I'm using webpack and I'm not sure how to do that, but I've tried (in webpack.config (in livescript, but it should be readable enough)):

```
resolve:
    modules:
        'node_modules'
    alias:
        'html5sortable': 'html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.min.js'
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: i guess you did this ? - load file you need from the dist/ directory, e.g. dist/html.sortable.min.js for the minified iife version.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'load file from dist/' actually means, why that is necessary, and how to do that. As I said I am using webpack.

Comment: so that means that you packed the sortable using webpack and then included the generated bundle using `<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Not sure what you mean (sorry, new to this), but in webpack.config I tried (to no avail):

resolve:
        modules:
            'app/scripts'
            'node_modules'
        alias:
             'html5sortable': 'html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.min.js'

Comment: include your webpack.config in the question with the proper formating, I have never use it so is even more "new to me" ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Turns out webpack can only handle javascript files that export a module. In html5sortable's case this is the CommonJS bundle. So that's what I had to include in webpack.config:

```
resolve:
    modules:
        'node_modules'
    alias:
        'html5sortable': 'html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.cjs'
```

After that I could simply 'require' the library and use it:

```
sortable = require 'html5sortable'

sortable '.sortable'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me anyway

```
import sortable from "html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.cjs";


sortable('.sortable', {handle: ".drag-handle"});
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

in my package.json file:

```
"html5sortable": "^0.13.3",
```

js:

```
import sortable from "html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.es.js"; // before initialization of sortable()


sortable('.o-sortable', {
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    placeholderClass: 'ph-class',
    hoverClass: 'bg-maroon yellow',
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="o-sortable">
    <li class="bg-maroon" style="padding: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 10" role="option">Item 1</li>
    <li class="bg-maroon" style="padding: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 10" role="option">Item 2</li>
    <li class="bg-maroon" style="padding: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 10" role="option">Item 3</li>
    <li class="bg-maroon" style="padding: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 10" role="option">Item 4</li>
    <li class="bg-maroon" style="padding: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 10" role="option">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add
`export default sortable`
at the end of node_modules/html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.js
then
`import sortable from 'html5sortable'`
worked