# Trouble importing ES6 module installed via VPM with Webpack into Javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am using Webpack to compile the ES6 Javascript in my webapp. I installed a plugin ([Html5Sortable](https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable)) via NPM and it now resides in my node_modules folder.

My Webpack entry point is `./src/app.js`. In this file I call another ES6 class called InputBoxPane:

```
import './InputBoxPane.scss';
import InputBoxPaneTemplate from './InputBoxPane.handlebars';
import 'html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.es.js';

export default class InputBoxPane {
    // Other code

    SetupDraggable() {
        sortable('.input-element-container', {
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            placeholderClass: 'ph-class',
            hoverClass: 'bg-maroon yellow'
        });
    }
}
```

You can see on line 3 that I am trying to import the html5sortable file that exists in node_modules:

[image]

I have tried every incarnation of `import html5sortable from 'html5sortable/dist/htmlsortable.es.js` you can imagine.

Although the code compiles, I am getting an error in my browser that says "sortable cannot be found". When I reference the Html5Sortable .js file in an old fashioned  tag everything works fine, so it looks like the file isn't being included in my bundle properly.

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: './src/app.js'
    } ,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')
    },
    devtool: isDevelopment && "source-map",
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../src"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.handlebars$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment,
                            minimize: !isDevelopment
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            autoprefixer: {
                                browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
                            },
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment,
                            plugins: () => [
                                autoprefixer
                            ]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'static/',
                            useRelativePath: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                          mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true,
                            quality: 65
                          },
                          optipng: {
                            enabled: true,
                          },
                          pngquant: {
                            quality: '65-90',
                            speed: 4
                          },
                          gifsicle: {
                            interlaced: false,
                          },
                          webp: {
                            quality: 75
                          }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ] 
    },
    plugins: [
        /** Since Webpack 4 */
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
              handlebarsLoader: {}
            }
          }),
          new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name]-styles.css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
          }),  

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'My awesome service',
            template: './src/index.handlebars',
            minify: !isDevelopment && {
                html5: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                caseSensitive: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeEmptyElements: true
            },

          })
      ]
  };
```

Comment: There is a non-validated answer here, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758078/how-to-include-html5sortable-in-your-project

Answer (score 0):

If it's in `node_modules` you should use `require`:

```
require("html5sortable/dist/html5sortable.es");
```